# How to create Recurring Tasks?

Tags: 2010, tasks

I need to set reminders from a Task list to specific people without human intervention. I want reminders for updates every week from the list. Is it possible to do it without using Calendar?

My Scenario is as follows:
I want a Task to be created in a name of a person every Monday with a due date on Wednesday.

Comment: Simple request, but yet, so hard to do in Sharepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use Sharepoint Designer and setup a workflow. Workflows works without human intervention.  Have a look at this article which explains: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-HA101859249.aspx?CTT=3

Comment: Thanks! The article is good but too generic. Do you have anything specific?

Comment: Hi Saumilm. Your requirements is quite specific , so i doubt you'll find a blog/article which delves into creating that type of workflow. I suggest you get yourself Sharepoint designer and start playing around with it by creating a new workflow. You'll find the designer quite easy to work with and within a few hours you'll be done with your wofklow.

Answer (score 0):

This article has detailed steps with snapshots
http://wiki.plexhosted.com/kb/How_to_Guides:How_to_create_a_recurring_task_workflow_via_SharePoint_Designer_2010